# Probability of location based on cell tower signal strength

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm tackling the following problem:

> Your cell phone is constantly trying to keep track of where you are. At any given point in time, for all nearby locations, your phone stores a probability that you are in that location. Right now your phone believes that you are in one of 16 different locations arranged in a grid with the following probabilities (see the figure on the left):
>
> [image]
>
> Your phone connects to a known cell tower and records two bars of signal. For each grid location $L_i$ you know the probability of observing two bars from this particular tower, given that the cell phone is in location $L_i$ (see the figure on the right).
>
> Example: the highlighted cell on the left figure means that you believed there was a $0.05$ probability that the user was in the bottom right grid cell prior to observing the cell tower signal. The highlighted cell on the right figure means that you think the probability of observing two bars, given the user was in the bottom right grid cell, is $0.75$.
>
> For each of the $16$ location positions, calculate the new probability that the user is in each location given the cell tower observation. Write a program to calculate the probabilities.

My approach of tackling this as of now: let $B$ represent the event of observing two bars. Then for the first location, the posterior probability would be

$$P(L_i\ |\ B) = \frac{P(B\ |\ L_i)P(L_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^{16}P(B\ |\ L_j)P(L_j)}$$

But suppose that I do this for the first tower and calculate $P(L_1\ |\ B)$. That'll become the new prior for location $L_1$. I'm a bit confused on how to approach, say, calculating the posterior for $L_2$. I know I'll use this equation:

$$P(L_2\ |\ B) = \frac{P(B\ |\ L_2)P(L_2)}{\sum_{j=1}^{16}P(B\ |\ L_j)P(L_j)}$$

but the denominator includes $P(L_1)$. One way is to just use the value of $P(L_1)$ given in the grid, i.e., $0.05$, but I think the "new prior" value of $P(L_1)$ (i.e. $P(L_1\ |\ B)$ that we calculated in the first step) should be used.

This is well and good, but won't the order of calculating the posterior probabilities of different locations determine the final set of values of posteriors, provided we're updating the priors in each step? Am I overthinking or does the question further need to specify **in which order** we're calculating the probabilities for the locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum in the denominator is calculating $P(B)$, which is unlikely to go well (mathematically) if it includes probabilities calculated from assuming B to be true.

To get to $P(B)$ the sum combines the individual likelihoods of B happening in **ALL** of the locations, where **ALL** means ${\sum_{j=1}^{16}P(L_j)=1}$ , any new information affecting our estimates of the $P(L_j)$ must obey this rule.

I think the context is confusing, since it's hard to make sense of the data in the left hand table, which needs to be thought of separately to the phone signal. It might be easier to think of the phone user as being continually moving and in each location 5% or 10% of the time, rather than a fixed unknown location.